# Job page: All companies are "Founded 1997"

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

On the [jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) page, if you click a few posts you will notice that all companies that have the "About us" widget on the right show `Founded 1997`.

But if you click on the company info widget (to get to the company detail page), you will see the correct `Founded $year` information.

Comment: Good spot, fixing now!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hmmm, that was hard-coded... Blame has been attributed and the person concerned has been sent to the corner to think about their actions.

Thanks for the report!

Comment: wow that was fast, nice one :)

Comment: Does the person responsible have to bring treats to the office, as punishment? :P

Comment: @Cerbrus unfortunately most of us work remotely so they're standing in the corner of their *own* office and we have no way of getting treats :/

Comment: one of the real downsides of working remotely...